# How I can insert bytes in a FileStream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, byte, filestream

If I have a file with this data:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A
```

When I try to insert byte FF, for example, between 01 and 02, the new file will be something like that:

```
01 FF 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A
```

But I'd like to insert that byte instead of replace one. How can I do it?

```
01 FF 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` ... followed by `File.WriteAllBytes`?

Comment: Use byte array.  Insert based from the right to your hole, once at hole insert new value, insert remaining values.  Really there are a few ways to this, in basic format it's just byte array node shifts. (See @Fredou answer)

Comment: You need to do this when you are reading or using the bytes but we really can't give you a specific answer unless we see specific code.

Comment: Just to clarify what others are not saying directly: The file system does allow for inserting data within a file - only for appending or rewriting from a certain point.

Answer (score 3):

1. you need to create a new array with the proper size
2. insert all bytes before 02 in the same order
3. insert the new bytes
4. you have to shift all bytes, from 02, to the right

so mostly this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var insertInPos = 1;

            var inBytes = new byte[] {01 ,02 ,03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0x0A };

            var insertBytes = new byte[] {0xFF, 0xDD};

            var newBytes = InsertBytes(inBytes, insertBytes, insertInPos);
        }

        public static byte[] InsertBytes(byte[] inBytes, byte[] insertBytes, int insertInPos)
        {
            var insertLen = insertBytes.Length - 1;

            var outBytes = new byte[inBytes.Length + insertLen + 1];
            var outLen = outBytes.Length - 1;

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < outLen; ++i)
            {
                if (i < insertInPos)
                {
                    outBytes[i] = inBytes[i];
                }
                else if (i == insertInPos)
                {
                    while (j <= insertLen)
                    {
                        outBytes[i + j] = insertBytes[j++];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    outBytes[i + insertLen] = inBytes[i - insertLen];
                }
            }

            return outBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 int index=1;

        byte item=01;
            List<byte> by = new List<byte>();
            string path = "Path here";
            Byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            by = b.ToList();
            by.Insert(index, item);
```

Comment: Insert takes two arguments Insert(int index, T item)